# Init scripts. Distinction of booting and starting activity

Tags: shell-script, rhel, boot, init-script, init.d

I have some script that runs and shuts down some service placed into `/etc/init.d`. It has symbolic link into `/etc/rc5.d` added with `chkconfig` for autolaunch on booting. Hence it starts on boot and can be controlled through `service myscript start`, `service myscript stop` etc manually by user. As it is known, sequence described in `start` section is executed on boot. But I also need to perform some activity **only** on boot without giving explicit access to perform this activity manually by user when system is already booted. In [this article](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/techref/initscripts) there is described that we can add `boot()` sequence into script and it will be performed only on boot. But that thing doesn't work. I tried different ways: writing it as `boot()` and `function boot()` but result is same: it doesn't work. So there are some questions occur: is it distributive-specific feature or may be this sequence must be at certain place of the script? If both are wrong (or maybe if all that stuff with `boot()` is wrong or deprecated), how can I perform some actions only on boot? My system is `Linux Red Hat Enterprise 6`.

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Some comments here

#some inclusions of another scripts here

function startService()
{
      #some activity for launching
}
boot()
{
        #That's it. Here I want to perform some preparations (remove files)
        #and then launch starting sequence:
        if [ -f "somefilename" ]
        then
            rm -f "somefilename"
        fi
        startService
}
function stopService()
{
        #Activity for stopping
}

#Some functions for service's status retrieving here

case "$1" in
        start)
                startService
                ;;
        stop)
                stopService
                ;;
        status)
                #Calls of status functions
                ;;
        *)
                echo "Usage: {start | stop | status}"
                exit 1
                ;;
esac
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a working sample?  If not, you might try to make code that reproduces the problem.  I notice the other functions are using the `function` keyword, yet your boot function does not.  Maybe you should try using `function boot()`?

Comment: Yes, that is working sample (except that stuff with boot()). I tried do it with "function" and without it. Maybe I overlooked some important trifle about init scripts? Because if I content of boot() in another place (at the top of file, for example) it works fine during boot but in that case these actions are performed on every calling of this script.

Comment: Why do you want to remove some files only at boot?  Why don't you keep the files in the `/tmp` directory.  Those files all get automatically removed at boot.

Comment: Actually I want to remove file from `/tmp` because files from there wasn't deleted at boot. After that issue I understood that I can't rely on autocleanup (at least when system crashed eg when power went down). Also here http://askubuntu.com/questions/20783/how-is-the-tmp-directory-cleaned-up and here http://serverfault.com/questions/377348/when-does-tmp-get-cleared I found an answer that cleaning of `/tmp` may be hang on `cron` in RHEL, so it seems that files from `/tmp` can be cleaned when I don't expect that (so that file will be deleted too). Hence it seems that I need another solution.

Comment: I mean, solution without hoping at /tmp cleanup

Comment: I don't know how that specific init system works.  I'm only familiar with debian flavors and the original systemV style init.  That's why I didn't submit an answer.  It would be interesting to know _why_ you have such a requirement, but that's not necessarily within the scope of your question.  I would prefer the software to manage the lifetime of the files during runtime.

Comment: I found a decision of my problem (it was about controlling of amount of running application's samples in accordance to the fact that power can suddenly go down hence there is necessity of manual cleanup of files at launch). Answer was found here (maybe someone will be interested in it, but it is in russian): http://www.linux.org.ru/forum/development/706506. Nevertheless question asked here is still interesting for cases of different situations. @RobertL, from your answer I got that it is bad practicing to rely on manual pre-launching preparations on boot. Is it correct?

Comment: Hmm... Read your comment one more time carefully. As I understood, this thing with `boot()` is distributive-specific, isn't it?

Comment: Just a thought, but if the file is only read/written by one process, that process can unlink (`rm`) the file from the filesystem, while still reading and writing it.  Whenever the process closes the file (or exits), the file data will be deleted from disk.

Comment: If you have the privilege to add init scripts, then do you have the privileges to control the /tmp cleaning policy?  In original unix, tmp files were removed only at boot, and you should be able to use this policy.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with init scripts having a boot() section, so it may be something specific to OpenWRT or busybox. In RHEL6, init scripts only get called with a "start" parameter, never a "boot" parameter.

To get a script to run at boot-time in RHEL6, you need to configure a "conf file" for Upstart in the /etc/init directory. I would suggest looking at /etc/init/rc.conf as a starting example. Name it something like *myscript.conf*, and populate it with something like this:

```
# adjust the runlevels if you don't want to run myscript in every runlevel
start on runlevel [0123456]

# this tells init to just run this once and let it exit
task

# if you want to see the output from your script on the console, use the following line; otherwise remove it
console output

# call myscript with a boot flag (to keep one copy of your script in /etc/init.d; adjust this if you'd rather have a separate boot-script)
exec /etc/init.d/myscript boot
```

See more information about upstart's init in `man -s5 init`.

Comment: That's seems interesting. I will try it and report results here after solving more urgent tasks. Thanks, Jeff.